# xampp internal server error 500 on windows

Tags: php, xampp, internal-server-error

I am using xampp installer version of xampp BAsic Package (version 1.8.0) for windows. I have a project named my-proj under the htdocs directory. When I open the main page of this project, the main page opens but from the main page whenever I cilck on any other link the following error message is shown:

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:xxxx/.../abc.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

There is an .htaccess file in my project directory /my-proj/public_html/.htaccess and the content of the .htaccess file is as follows:

```
#####errorpage#####
#ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
#####end:errorpage#####
```

I have tried in to run my project in both ways - (1) by activating the line LoadModule rewrite_module Modules/mod_rewrite.so in the htpd.conf file in c:\xampp\apache\conf and changing the lines AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in htpd.conf file and (2) By deactivatiing the line of mod_rewrite in htpd.conf and by deleting the .htaccess file, but I failed to run my project.

Any ideas about how to solve this problem or could anybody suggest what should be the contents of a .htaccess file?

Comment: More interesting are the contents of your script. 500 error can mean anything. It can be htaccess file or it can be application/php fatal error

Comment: Vitaly Dyatlov, is there anything wrong in my .htaccess file? Do I need to edit this file? Please reply if you know.